# In Ubuntu 17.10, how do you get your workspaces on both monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors, workspaces, 17.10, gnome-shell

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10 from 17.04.
When I try to switch workspaces, it only does so on the primary monitor. The secondary monitor can not switch workspaces (It is stuck on Workspace 1).
How can I switch workspaces on both monitors?